Using the data uri of a react-camera-pro image
I used the react-camera-pro to capture an image and have the data uri (in this format: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ....) stored in Firebase. Is there a way to use this to actually see the image I captured, or maybe to download it locally?
I've looked into changing the uri into a usable image url, but I'm not too experienced with this and I'm not sure if this is the best method.

A data URL contains all of the data right there encoded in the URL in base64 format.  You need to write some code to convert that to some actual image data that would be useful for whatever you're trying to do.  Since you haven't really specified exactly what you want to do with that resulting image or what language you want to use to accomplish this, I've marked several questions as duplicates for you to consider.  Also consider doing a web search to find a more relevant solution for your needs (I found all those with a web search.)
